# Ubuntu update 11.10 to 12.04 crashed

Tags: 12.04, partial-upgrade

I was recently trying to update my laptop running on 11.10 to 12.04 in update manager and in the middle of the update, my update froze. So I waited for an hour before I decided to restart my computer. When I restarted it, it had a black, not a purple, screen that kept flashing and I cant do anything. There is absolutely no gui interface and I cant do anything. Does anyone know how I can fix this? I have a disk with Ubuntu 11.10 on it. I don't any files cause I have a backup, I just need the computer working. Can you please help me fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Do you get a `grub` interface immediately after the BIOS does its things? Can you edit the kernel command line? If you edit it to add `single`, do you get a usable shell?

Comment: I dont know what a grub interface is, but all I see is a black screen that keeps flashing and there is no terminal

Answer (score 1):

See if you can get into the bios:

http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000192.htm

Set it to boot from the cd (you can do this with USB too), put a cd (or USB stick) in that has the Ubuntu version (e.g. .iso cd) and reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't need to save any data, the easiest solution would be to re-install 11.10 from the CD/ DVD you have. Just insert the CD/ DVD, restart the laptop and follow the steps - it should be pretty easy.

I would create another CD/ DVD with 12.04 though, and install it directly. Good luck!

Comment: I put my cd inside and it doesn't work.  I don't know how to make it work. Any Ideas Pleeaase??? Thanks!!!

Comment: What brand of laptop is it?

Comment: hp pavilion dv2000. Is there a way I can fix it?

Comment: You should be able to boot from the CD following the instructions [here](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01443326&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en&product=18703). In short, just press ESC as soon as the laptop starts/ reboots, then *F9* for **Boot Option Menu** and then select **Internal CD/DVD ROM Drive**. This should tell the laptop to boot from the CD and you will be able to reinstall 11.10

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu usually crashes and shows some bugs if you upgrade it, via CD/DVD or online upgrade.

I used to clear install it, make sure the current version on computer be formatted from hard drive and start fresh install the latest version.

Comment: it's based on my experience. it's not absolutely for your recommendation

Comment: I cant install it. I tried re-installing ubuntu 11.10 with my cd and it did not work. Are there any other ways I can install it? Is there a way I can reach terminal? If I do, what commands should I type in? Thanks!

Comment: just format **root** partition (mark as "/" [slash]) before.. and it will perfectly work.

if it can't, there's something wrong with installer. maybe checksum is not right.